# string was not recognized as a valid datetime while assigning the value to Nullable DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, nullable

I have a textbox from which I am sending date as string in 'MM/dd/yyyy' formate, and when I am assigning that value to nullable datetime property value getting the error as string was not recognized as a valid datetime, I am converting the string as below then also getting the same error

```
private Tbl_UserDetails GetAnnouncementInformation(Tbl_UserDetails userDetails, Dictionary<string, object> details)
{
  userDetails.JoiningDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(details["JoiningDate "].ToString()) ?
                            (DateTime?)null : 
                             DateTime.ParseExact(details["JoiningDate "].ToString(),
                             "MM/dd/yyyy", null);

  userDetails.JoiningDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(details["JoiningDate "].ToString()) ?
                            (DateTime?)null : 
                             DateTime.ParseExact(details["JoiningDate "].ToString(),
                             "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

In both the way I am getting the same error. Please help me in this.

Comment: What is the value of `details["JoiningDate "].ToString()` and your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint and see what the contents of `JoiningDate`? What were the contents?

Comment: I am getting "08/25/2014" as string value

Comment: @Rocky So, you are saying; `DateTime.ParseExact("08/25/2014", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` throws `FormatException`? It doesn't. The problem can be somewhere else?

Comment: FYI you don't need to cast as `null` as `DateTime?`, `null` is an acceptable return type for any nullable type.

Comment: Just another reminder what a *terrible* idea it is to store dates as string in a dbase column.

Comment: Clearly *something* isn't right with your code, however, the example you have given can't match what your code really looks like because the example code/data [works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IEqdCD).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
DateTime tempDate;
userDetails.JoiningDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(
  details["JoiningDate "].ToString(), 
  "MM/dd/yyyy", 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
  DateTimeStyles.None, 
  out tempDate) 
? tempDate 
: (DateTime?)null;
```

With extention of :

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static DateTime? GetNullableDateTime(
        this String str, string format = "MM/dd/yyyy")
    {
        DateTime tempDate;
        var result = DateTime.TryParseExact(str, format, 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tempDate) 
        ? tempDate 
        : default(DateTime?);
        return result;
    }
}
```

It would look like:

```
userDetails.JoiningDate = 
    details["JoiningDate "].ToString().GetNullableDateTime();
```

Example program

```
Assert.IsNull("sddfsdf".GetNullableDateTime());
Assert.IsNotNull("10/20/2014".GetNullableDateTime());
Assert.IsNotNull("20.10.2014".GetNullableDateTime("dd.MM.yyyy"));
```

Comment: I have used this, but in an extension method.

Comment: Why do you cast `null` as `(DateTime?)`? Just return `null`.

Comment: @James If you have static content checkers they will give an error there. Reason is that **null** does not convey any type information. I am not sure however if **default(DateTime?)** would have intended value.

Comment: I was going to also suggest `default(DateTime?)` but that ultimately would just return `null`. However, regardless if I used static type checkers I'd say scenarios like these are exceptions to the rule.

Comment: I am getting null as return value, not getting the date

Comment: What value will **details["JoiningDate "].ToString()** result as?

Comment: I have "08/22/2014 00:00:00" value in that, which is string type

Comment: Well try **.GetNullableDateTime("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")** or change default value **string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"**.