# Error in "DateTime.ParseExact" when using Nullable DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a `Nullable DateTime`, and I got an error :

> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I looked at  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480733/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-while-assigning-the-value-to-nulla), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316622/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-parameter-for-datetime-parseexact),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014101/datetime-format-issue-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime) . I also tried `String.Format("{0:s}", dateTime)`, but it does not change my `DateTime` format.My code is like below,

```
if (person.JsonData.PasswordChangeRequestTime != null)
{
     DateTime data;  
     data = DateTime.ParseExact(((DateTime)person.JsonData.PasswordChangeRequestTime).Date.ToStringDateTime(), "dd'-'MM'-'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);   
     person.setColumnValue("passwordchangerequesttime", data);
}
```

One of my `DateTime` is like this:
`1/1/2015 2:00:00 PM`
I want them in a format of 
`1-1-2015 14:00:00`
what is wrong with my `DateTime.ParseExact` function?

By the way, I do not want to use `subString` function!

Comment: What's this method - `ToStringDateTime()`?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I thought it might convert it to string! it does not work for `(DateTime)person.JsonData.PasswordChangeRequestTime).Date.ToString()`

Comment: You start with `DateTime` - but it is very unclear what end result of your operation should be (looks like `DateTime` again). Would not just `data = person.JsonData.PasswordChangeRequestTime;` work?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that does not work too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do *anything*.

Your `(DateTime)person.JsonData.PasswordChangeRequestTime` *already* a `DateTime`, what you see this is probably in a debugger or something.

A `DateTime` does not have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values. Format concept only matter when you get it's *textual* (string) representation which is usually done with `DateTime.ToString()` method.

If you wanna get exact string representation of it, you can use `ToString` method with proper format and culture settings like;

```
((DateTime)person.JsonData.PasswordChangeRequestTime)
                          .ToString("d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

genereates `1/1/2015 2:00:00 PM` and

```
((DateTime)person.JsonData.PasswordChangeRequestTime)
                          .ToString("d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

generates `1-1-2015 14:00:00` formatted strings.

If your `1/1/2015 2:00:00 PM` is `string`, not a `DateTime`, you need to parse it to `DateTime` with proper format first then generate it's string representation with proper format as well.

```
string s = "1/1/2015 2:00:00 PM";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.ToString("d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    // Generates 1-1-2015 14:00:00
}
```

Comment: thank @Soner Gönül! One of my DateTime is like this: `1/1/2015 2:00:00 PM` I want them in a format of `1-1-2015 14:00:00`!!! it does not work for `((DateTime)person.JsonData.PasswordChangeRequestTime)`!!! By the way, I do not want to use `subString` function!

Comment: I have also tried `data = ((DateTime)person.JsonData.PasswordChangeRequestTime).ToString("d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` but there is an error :`Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'system.DateTime'`

Comment: @DooshizePlusPlus Edited my answer. Take a look. Your code won't compile because `ToString` method returns `string` but you try to assign it to `data` which is `DateTime` and there is no implicit conversation between them.

Comment: @SonerGönül I suspect the concept of "DateTime does not include formatting" is way too complex for most people. I'm not sure if you could have made your post better to explain it so :(

Comment: Thanks! I used  `person.setColumnValue("passwordchangerequesttime", ((DateTime)person.JsonData.PasswordChangeRequestTime).ToString("d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))`!  and @SonerGönül the format is exactely `DateTime` not `string`!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Amen to that. No matter how clear you try explain, some people _just_ won't get it. This is the best explanation I can made, so.. :)